# Spring MVC - Child entity lost after submit

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, binding, controller

I'm going to try to explain my problem as completely and shortly as I can...

A web application, made on Spring MVC 2.5 + Hibernate + Java 6 (not using annotation!).

I've got a controller extending SimpleFormController and a jsp page that is its formView and successView.

This controller should help me to insert into db an entity PracticeT that has connected (many to one) a lookup entity PracticeConfT (think about it as a "typology"). I need to choose that "typology" through a drop-down menu. In my webapp I need to be able to save data inserted and when I want, to submit the request for approval.

The page has some text fields and that drop-down menu. The bean called as default "command" is NewPracticeBean that has within a reference to an object PracticeT.

THE PROBLEM IS: I fill the form, I select a typology from the drop-down menu, I submit form and save data on DB but when I come back to the view, every property is there but the drop-down menu it is not: it has all the options allowed but no one selected. Some checks revealed that the entity PracticeConfT is null (but it has been recorded on db correctly and debugging it is still there in the model until the very end of the method onSubmit!!!).

I hope someone can help me. Thank you in advance!
Bye,
Dolfiz

Here some useful code:
(I don't think that hibernate config can be the problem, but if you need it, I can post it too)

**newPractice.jsp**

```
<form:form id="newPracticeForm" commandName="command">
    <input type="hidden" name="action"/>
    <spring:nestedPath path="practiceT">
        <table class="table-data-form">
            <tr>
                <td class="left"><spring:message code="" text="Practice type" /></td>
                <td>
                    <form:select path="practiceConfT" multiple="false">
                        <form:option value="" label="- seleziona -"/>
                        <form:options items="${practiceTypeList}" itemValue="idPracticeConf" itemLabel="practiceName"/> 
                    </form:select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="left">
                    <spring:message code="" text="Opzione divisa" />
                    <br/><form:errors cssClass="errors" path="opzioneDivisa" />
                </td>
                <td><form:input path="opzioneDivisa" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="1">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Save" class="buttonEMS" style="width:100px;" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </spring:nestedPath>
</form:form>
```

**NewPracticeBean.java**

```
public class NewPracticeBean implements Serializable{

    private PracticeT practiceT;
    private String action;
    private boolean typeSelected;

    public NewPracticeBean(){
        super();
        this.practiceT = new PracticeT();
    }

    // getters & setters...
}
```

**PracticeT.java**

```
public class PracticeT implements java.io.Serializable {

    private long idPractice;
    private PracticeConfT practiceConfT;
    private String opzioneDivisa;

    // getters & setters...
}
```

**PracticeConfT.java**

```
public class PracticeConfT implements java.io.Serializable {

    public static final String PRACTICE_NAME = "practiceName";

    private long idPracticeConf;
    private String practiceName;

    // getters & setters...
}
```

**NewPracticeController.java**
    public class NewPracticeController extends SimpleFormController{

```
    protected SmartLogger log = SmartLogger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private PracticeSu practiceSu;
    private ConfigurationSu configurationSu;

    private HibernateEntityDataBinder practiceConfTBinder;
    private HibernateEntityDataBinder practiceTBinder;

    public NewPracticeController() {
        setCommandClass(NewPracticeBean.class);
        setCommandName("command");
    }

    @Override
    protected void initBinder(HttpServletRequest request, ServletRequestDataBinder binder) throws Exception {
        log.trace("NewPracticeController -- initBinder");
        super.initBinder(request, binder);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(PracticeT.class, "practiceT", practiceTBinder);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(PracticeConfT.class, "practiceT.practiceConfT", practiceConfTBinder);
    }

    @Override
    protected Map referenceData(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        log.trace("NewPracticeController -- referenceData");
        Map model = new HashMap();
        RetrieveAllEntitiesReq req = new RetrieveAllEntitiesReq();
        req.setEntity(PracticeConfT.class);
        req.setOrderProperty(PracticeConfT.PRACTICE_NAME);
        RetrieveAllEntitiesResp resp = configurationSu.retrieveAllEntities(req);
        List entitiesList = resp.getEntitiesList();
        model.put("practiceTypeList", entitiesList);

        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView onSubmit(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object command, BindException errors) throws Exception {
        NewPracticeBean practiceBean = (NewPracticeBean)command;
        Map model = errors.getModel();

        CreateNewPracticeReq req = new CreateNewPracticeReq();
        req.setPracticeT(practiceBean.getPracticeT());
        CreateNewPracticeResp resp = practiceSu.createNewPractice(req);
        practiceBean.setPracticeT(resp.getPracticeT());

        model.putAll(referenceData(null));
        model.put(getCommandName(), practiceBean);

        return new ModelAndView(getSuccessView(), model);
    }

    // setters and getters...
}
```

Comment: I would like to underline that:
- in the jsp page the PracticeConfT is null
- the same PracticeConfT is not null in the onSubmit method before the return statement

Comment: Try to add an Equals Method to the PracticeConfT, because I guess it is equals but not same!

Comment: Should I use fromBackingObject method to retrieve the PracticeConfT and set it in PracticeT before the form is rendered? It seems so weird... I guessed that the binding was automatic... I'm sure I'm missing something important... >:(

Comment: I don't understand why equality can affect this. What do you mean? The problem is that on server PracticeConfT is not null, but on jsp page is null >:S

Comment: @Dolfiz my idea was that <form:options> "sets the 'selected' attribute as appropriate based on the bound value." is based on the equals method. (But after rethinking now, I am not so sure anymore. I will check this later but now I will explain what a meant). And if the entity: PracticeT.practiceConfT is not the SAME object like the once in ` model.put("practiceTypeList", entitiesList)` and no correct equals method is implemented then the right object is not selected.

Comment: @Ralph Blame on me! Sorry Ralph, you are absolutely right! The problem was that, the equals() method, because I realized that the PracticeConfT is not null on jsp and I need to learn to use better <c:out> tag... >:/ If you resend your previous reply I'd gladly vote it >;) Bye and thanks again!

Comment: @Dolfiz I have undelete my old answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending some time with `OptionsTag`, `OptionWriter` and `SelectValueComparator`, I would say, then output of "selected" is based on Object.equals.

So if for any reason (Lazyloading...) the Object `PracticeT.practiceConfT` and the according Objects of `model.put("practiceTypeList", entitiesList)` are not the SAME (==) then `forms:options` will not select them as long as the equals method is not correct implemented.

So I guess you need to implement a correct equals method, even if this did not fix this problem, it is always better to have a correct equals method than a wrong or none.

---

Correct implemented means that it must pay attention to the fact that is used with Hibernate. (for example use `if (Hibernate.getClass(this)  != Hibernate.getClass(other))`  instead of `if (this.getClass()  != other.getClass() )

Comment: Thank you Ralph for your suggestions. What you said makes sense, of course, but the point is that in the jsp, after the submit, PracticeConfT is null. With a <c:out value='${practiceConfT.practiceName}'/> I should be able to show its value - though its equal or not to some object listed in the drop-down - instead it's null.

Comment: It seams that I do not have misunderstood you problem - sorry